I want my id column in jquery datatable to not be searchable so user cant get a row based on id in searchbar
I have a table which gets data from backend and is populated in frontend using a loop and then make a datatable for it , but i have issue that in datatable search box the row can be searched with id too which is for development purpose only and we want it should not be used to search , i made a column for id at index 0 and give its visible to false. I paste this code in datatable code
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ]
   

While visibility false is working fine still the searchable is not working , how can i stop row to be searched by that id.
I tried to ask chatgpt which give me this code which when didnt work i refer to datatable documentation which says to do same thing, i was expecting to find the reason why my code is not working and to fix it.

May be there is another column with similar data to the ID field. Test with another field to ensure syntax is correct (" around attributes and [] around 0 seems unnecessary).

There are no other column with id but one column is taking id in data attributes.I did check with another field and it was working fine for other columns

_ one column is taking id in data attributes_ : set the searchable for that column to false and check again.
